# Passing a URL variable into xsl in sharepoint 2013

Tags: xml, xslt, sharepoint

I  use xsl to reformat a list in sharepoint 2013 and I want to implement paging in the new list. 
So, first I want to know how to pass parameters from the url and read it from xsl.

https://stackoverflow.com/search.aspx?page=2

I want to get "page" value.

I use this code , but never work for me.

```
 <xsl:param name="page"/>
```

and I read it like

```
<xsl:value-of select="$page" />
```

I almost finish my work and I want to just know how to read the URL variable .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work for me after I modify the original view xml from sharepoint physical folder under XSL (main.xsl).

I think it related to security problem, and when I create external xsl file and liked it with sharepoint list it will be not have the full trust !!

Answer (score 1):

Use @page instead of $page

`<xsl:value-of select="@page" />`